# Converting data type inside OBJECT_CONSTRUCT in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake's [Object_Construct](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html) to create a JSON array with values.

Example:

```
Select  OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
        user_id,    user.id::TIMESTAMP,
        join_date,  user.create_date
       )
from user
```

`Select object_construct(*) from above_table` This is giving me the output as follows

```
|-------------------------------------------|
|              OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)          |
|-------------------------------------------|
| {                                         |
|   "user_id": 1,                           |
|   "join_date": "2021-06-18 19:51:19.000"  |
| }                                         |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

Can the join_date inside JSON be converted to timestamp data-type instead of STRING as the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON does not have a "date" data type, it has [numbers, bool, string](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp). Thus you ether need to store dates/timestamps as epoch seconds/milliseconds, or as formatted string.

```
SELECT 
    try_to_timestamp_ntz('2021-06-18 19:51:19.000') as t
    ,date_part('epoch_second', t) as epoch_s
    ,date_part('epoch_millisecond', t) as epoch_ms
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(epoch_s, 0) as time_from_sec    
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(epoch_ms, 3) as time_from_ms;
```

giving:

| T | EPOCH_S | EPOCH_MS | TIME_FROM_SEC | TIME_FROM_MS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-18 19:51:19.000 | 1624045879 | 1624045879000 | 2021-06-18 19:51:19.000 | 2021-06-18 19:51:19.000 |

Ah so, you error on using the JSON will be that the values from a VARIANT/json object are VARIENT so to pass those to things like TO_TIMESTAMP they need casting to `string`

So here is building, cast, and fetching out values:

```
Select
    user.id
    ,user.create_date
    ,OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
        'user_id',    user.id,
        'join_date',  user.create_date
       )::variant as json_data
   ,get(json_data, 'user_id') AS j_user_id_1
   ,json_data:user_id AS j_user_id_2
   ,get(json_data, 'join_date') AS j_user_create_date_1
   ,json_data:join_date AS j_user_create_date_2
   ,j_user_id_1::number as j_user_id_1_int
   ,j_user_create_date_2::timestamp as j_user_create_date_2_ts_a
   ,to_timestamp_ntz(j_user_create_date_2::string) as j_user_create_date_2_ts_b
   ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(j_user_create_date_2::string) as j_user_create_date_2_ts_c
FROM VALUES 
    (1, '2021-06-18 19:51:19.000' ) 
    AS user(id, create_date)
;
```

Comment: When I do ```try_to_timestamp_ntz(join_date.::TIMESTAMP)``` or ```try_to_timestamp_ntz(join_date)``` I'm getting an error: 
```TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types TIMESTAMP_TZ(9) and TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)```

Comment: `user.id` does not seem like a timestamp. and you first example makes no sense, if you have cast it to timestamp, why cast it to timestamp again. But I assume the question was about `join_date` and it being stored as a string, as that is what you have, and you ask about.

Comment: Sorry, join_date is only giving that error

Comment: as per the update you will need to cast to `string` thus `to_timestamp_ntz( json_data:join_date::string)`